# Photoshop: Keyboard shortcuts for swatches

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, adobe-photoshop

I would like to assign a different keyboard shortcut to each of the swatches that I load by default in my Photoshop projects.

I can do this recording by recording a different `Action` for the selection of each swatch and then assigning keyboard shortcuts to each of the recorded `Actions`. However, if I understand correctly, the keyboard shortcuts for `Actions` must use `Function keys`, which I do not find convenient (they are usually not near my fingers on my keyboard).

So here are my questions:

1. Is there an alternative way of assigning keyboard shortcuts to swatches in Photoshop (instead of recording actions)?
2. If not, is there a workaround that could allow me to use keyboard shortcuts for actions that do not involve `Function keys`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign keyboard shortcut from Edit>Keyboard shortcuts or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to go there. next, find swatch in windows section and click on it to assign new shortcut